# codewars kata: "Is my friend cheating?" Passed all test but using bruteforce, If someone could help me optimize my code by using actual math maybe?

Tags: javascript, typescript, loops, math, nested-loops

Here is my solution

```
export function removeNb (n:number):number[][] {
  const total = n * (n+1) / 2;
      
  for(let a = n; a > 1; a--){

    for(let b = a-1 ;b > 1 ; b--){

      if(total - b - a === b*a){

        return [[b,a],[a,b]]
      }
    }
  }
  return []
}
```

The problem is this:

> A friend of mine takes the sequence of all numbers from 1 to n (where
> n > 0).
>
> Within that sequence, he chooses two numbers, a and b.
>
> **He says that the product of a and b should be equal to the sum of all**
> **numbers in the sequence, excluding a and b.**
>
> Given a number n, could you tell me the numbers he excluded from the
> sequence?
>
> The function takes the parameter: n (n is always strictly greater than
> 0) and returns an array of arrays.

The test cases are as follows:

```
removeNb(26); //[[15,21],[21,15]]
removeNb(101); //[[55,91],[91,55]]
removeNb(102); //[[70,73],[73,70]]
removeNb(110); //[[70,85],[85,70]]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update**
As Ike mentioned the previous solution doesn't take in account the fact that a and b both need to be less or equal to n so the solution should be updated like this : (b needs to be less then n, ie `(total - a) / (a + 1) <= n` ie `(total - n) / (n + 1) <= a`)

```js
    function removeNb(n: number) {
        const total = n * (n + 1) / 2;
        const t: [number, number][] = [];
        for (let a = Math.ceil((total - n) / (n + 1)); a * a < total; a++) {
            const b = (total - a) / (a + 1)
            if (!(b % 1)) t.push([a,b],...(a === b ? [] : [[b,a]]))
        }
        return t
    }
```

---

With a bit of maths we can check that `tatal - a - b = a * b` is equivalent to `(total - a) / (a + 1) = b` so we can deduce b from a and just check if it is an integer.

Also since a and b are exchangeable we can require b to be greater or equal a i.e `(total - a) / (a + 1) >= a <=> total  >= a * (a + 2)` so we can require `a² < total`.

So your function can be optimized this way:

```js
    function removeNb(n: number) {
        const total = n * (n + 1) / 2;
        const t: [number, number][] = [];
        for (let a = 1; a * a < total; a++) {
            const b = (total - a) / (a + 1)
            if (!(b % 1)) t.push([a,b],...(a === b ? [] : [[b,a]]))
        }
        return t
    }
```

Comment: thank for this @Ahmed, your solution was exceeding 'n' and I needed to modify that and came up with this: `function removeNb(n: number):number[][] {
  const total = n * (n + 1) / 2;
  let result = []
  for (let a = Math.round(n/2); a < n; a++) {
    const b = (total - a) / (a + 1)
    if (!(b % 1) && b < n) result.push([a, b])
  }
  return result;
       
}`

Comment: Sry I've forget this condition, I've updated my answer based on your comment, thanks @Ikelagos